# Uncertain behaviour of Google Places API for russians addresses

Tags: json, google-places-api

Quite strange behaviour: sending request to Google Places API like this

```
 $request = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=' . urlencode(
            $place
        ) . '&types=geocode&regions=locality&language=ru&sensor=true&key=MY_KEY';
```

where request is:

```
$place = москв
```

or Калуга or Тверь

for russians cities I get strange combination:

```
"description" : "Rossiya, город Москва, Москва",
```

country in latin and city in cyrillic. Cyrillic is OK, but Rossiaya instead of Россия is confusing me.
At the same time for ukrainian address is good:

```
 "description" : "Московский проспект, Харьков, Харьковская область, Украина",
```

Full json here http://pastebin.com/G7R5ikbZ